# Multiple functions that perform same action on separate dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, html, function, menu, dropdown

In addition to the question asked here that was solved by [@Elezar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1082789/elezar):
[CSS focus does not change color after second clicking on dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644494/css-focus-does-not-change-color-after-second-clicking-on-dropdown-menu)

The example bellow:

```js
//dropdown_1
function dropdown_one(btn) {
  document.getElementById("menu_list").classList.toggle("dcontent");
  btn.classList.toggle("button-selected");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.button')) {

    var menu = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
      var open_list = menu[i];
      if (open_list.classList.contains('dcontent')) {
        open_list.classList.remove('dcontent');
      }
    }

    let selected = document.getElementsByClassName("button-selected");
    for (let i = 0, len = selected.length; i < len; i++) {
      selected[i].classList.remove("button-selected");
    }
  }
}
//dropdown_2
function dropdown_two(btn) {
  document.getElementById("menu_list2").classList.toggle("dcontent");
  btn.classList.toggle("button-selected2");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.button2')) {

    var menu = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content2");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
      var open_list = menu[i];
      if (open_list.classList.contains('dcontent')) {
        open_list.classList.remove('dcontent');
      }
    }

    let selected2 = document.getElementsByClassName("button-selected2");
    for (let i = 0, len = selected2.length; i < len; i++) {
      selected2[i].classList.remove("button-selected2");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.button, .button2 {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover, .button2:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
.button-selected,
.button-selected:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.button-selected2,
.button-selected2:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
.dropdown, .dropdown2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
.dropdown-content, .dropdown-content2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #efefef;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: 30px;
}
.dropdown-content a, .dropdown-content2 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown a:hover, .dropdown2 a:hover {
  background-color: grey
}
.dcontent {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="dropdown_one(this)" class="button">Dropdown1</button>
  <div id="menu_list" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">one</a>
    <a href="#">two</a>
    <a href="#">three</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown2">
  <button onclick="dropdown_two(this)" class="button2">Dropdown2</button>
  <div id="menu_list2" class="dropdown-content2">
    <a href="#">four</a>
    <a href="#">five</a>
    <a href="#">six</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result is odd.
On Dropdown_1 when dropdown list opens, the list won't go away when clicked outside the elements or on Dropdown_2.
I know there is something with the function combining, but I need help on this. I also would like to know how to add more dropdowns if needed.

Thank you,
CP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution, the problem was that the second dropdown button condition had to be placed inside window.onclick = function(event) and not as separate.

```js
//dropdowns
function dropdown_one(btn) {
  document.getElementById("menu_list").classList.toggle("dcontent");
  btn.classList.toggle("button-selected");
}
function dropdown_two(btn) {
  document.getElementById("menu_list2").classList.toggle("dcontent");
  btn.classList.toggle("button-selected2");
}
//condition
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.button')) {

    var menu = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
      var open_list = menu[i];
      if (open_list.classList.contains('dcontent')) {
        open_list.classList.remove('dcontent');
      }
    }

    let selected = document.getElementsByClassName("button-selected");
    for (let i = 0, len = selected.length; i < len; i++) {
      selected[i].classList.remove("button-selected");
    }
  }
  if (!event.target.matches('.button2')) {

    var menu = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content2");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
      var open_list = menu[i];
      if (open_list.classList.contains('dcontent')) {
        open_list.classList.remove('dcontent');
      }
    }

    let selected2 = document.getElementsByClassName("button-selected2");
    for (let i = 0, len = selected2.length; i < len; i++) {
      selected2[i].classList.remove("button-selected2");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.button, .button2 {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover, .button2:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
.button-selected,
.button-selected:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.button-selected2,
.button-selected2:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
.dropdown, .dropdown2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
.dropdown-content, .dropdown-content2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #efefef;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: 30px;
}
.dropdown-content a, .dropdown-content2 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown a:hover, .dropdown2 a:hover {
  background-color: grey
}
.dcontent {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="dropdown_one(this)" class="button">Dropdown1</button>
  <div id="menu_list" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">one</a>
    <a href="#">two</a>
    <a href="#">three</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown2">
  <button onclick="dropdown_two(this)" class="button2">Dropdown2</button>
  <div id="menu_list2" class="dropdown-content2">
    <a href="#">four</a>
    <a href="#">five</a>
    <a href="#">six</a>
  </div>
</div>
```